# Selenium/Chromedriver hangs on a new tab containing an alert

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to develop a scraper using selenium. Part of the scraping process is to download some pdf files. I download the files without having selenium to open a new tab, so I have included this options in my Chrome Options:

```
download_folder = os.path.join(current_directory,'downloads')
prefs = {
            "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally":True,
            "download.prompt_for_download": False,
            "download.directory_upgrade": True,
            "download.default_directory":download_folder
        }
```

I can download files, but sometimes selenium opens a new tab and an alert is there and the code freezes. I can't switch to that window nor accept that alert.

On the other hand, I could just download the file by using requests, but the site uses captchav3 and I already have reseted my ip 3 times because I'm not sending the token in the request.

How can I switch to the window that has the alert and accept it? Or just get the pdf I need without been blocked by recaptcha.

I can provide some code if needed.

EDIT: I did the following in order to reproduce the situation.

I created a mini flask app and included this 2 html files:

In alert.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
        <body>
            <a href="{{ url_for('test_alert') }}" target="_blank" id="test">Visit Alert test!</a>
        </body>
</html>
```

In test_alert.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("Hello world");
    </script>
</html>
```

flask app:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/',methods=['GET'])
def home():
    return render_template('alert.html')

@app.route('/test_alert',methods=['GET'])
def test_alert():
    return render_template('test_alert.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,port=8080)
```

Then, with selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
service = Service()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service,options = options)
driver.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/')
element = driver.find_element('xpath','//a')
element.click()
```

The moment the element is clicked, a new tab is opened and the alert is triggered, freezing the selenium code execution. How can I dismiss the alert and recover the control of selenium?

Comment: Provide the code! Yes, we will always need it!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Have you tried this doc? https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/alerts/#alerts

Comment: I tried, but I get a `TimeoutException` when `WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.alert_is_present())` is executed

Comment: [You can switch between windows/tabs](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/windows/#switching-windows-or-tabs) using `driver.switch_to.window(window_handle)`